# HTML Title is not centered

Tags: html

I am working on HTML code. I need the title of code be in center of page. The title of page (heading) contain 10 words.

The options i am using start the sentence from middle and then move to right. I need the whole .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style type="text/css">
    .Titleline {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      width: 546px;
      height: 74px;
      font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT;
      font-size: 35px;
      line-height: 1.06;
      color: #222222;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <center class="Titleline">You are one step closer to <br/>the experience of a life time</center>
    </tr>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

You see the sentence start at center but moves to right.

can this be fixed somehow.

Comment: Use a validator. Write valid HTML. Don't use tables for layout. Treat absolute positioning as a last resort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. There are two reasons:

1. `<center>` tag is deprecated. (Some browsers do support them).
2. `<center>` cannot be a direct descendant to `<tr>`, it should be `<td>`. Use the class for the `td` instead.

Better code would be something like:

```css
.Titleline {
  /* position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 546px;
  height: 74px;
  */
  font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 1.06;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="Titleline">You are one step closer to <br/>the experience of a life time</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See the updated code in the snippet. Use the class for the `<td>` instead and make the `<table>`, full width. Also, don't use `position` unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks work, this help me fix it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems:

- **[`<center>` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)**; don't use it.
- You have invalid markup; **[`<center>` is not a valid child of `<tr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr)**. 
  `<td>` and `<th>` are the only valid children of `<tr>`.
- You're using **[`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)** with **[`left: 50%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left)**, which makes your text start with an **offset** of 50%; it does not centralise it.

I'd recommend adding switching `<center>` to `<td>`, and adding **[`text-align: center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)** to `.Titleline` in order to centralise it. Keep in mind you've also got a fixed **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** on your `.Titleline`, which will need removing. You'll also need to add `width: 100%` to `table` so that it takes up the full available width (so that the text can centralise). This can be seen in the following example:

```css
.Titleline {
  font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 1.06;
  color: #222222;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="Titleline">You are one step closer to <br/>the experience of a life time</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

The above shows how you can centralise your text in a table, but I'd also recommend not using tables for layouts due to their poor support for smaller screens. I'd recommend making use of something like the **[`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)** element to divide up your content instead. For pure text (like your example), you should also make use of the **[`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)** tag:

```css
.Titleline {
  font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 1.06;
  color: #222222;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <p class="Titleline">You are one step closer to <br/>the experience of a life time</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: *`<td>` is the only valid child of `<tr>`* — There's `<th>` as well.

Comment: @Quentin -- Correct. I did know that, so I'm not sure why I didn't mention it. I probably meant that `<center>` is an invalid child, and then got lost in a train of thought. Anyway, I've updated the answer now to correct that :)

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <style type="text/css">
     .Titleline 
     {
              position: absolute;

              text-align:center;

        width: 546px;
              height: 74px;
              font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT;
              font-size: 35px;
              line-height: 1.06;    
              color: #222222;
         }
     </style>
   </head>
  <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
                  <td class="Titleline">
                      You are one step closer to <br/>the experience of a life time
                  </td>
               </tr>
  </table>  

      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Copied from mine?

Comment: And no explanation. `:)` Great...